# How to pass selected file path in listview to another form?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a media player.

first form of getting the file path to a text box but no use of it

When selecting media file in list view, we can play that video it is my concept, but I don't know how to pass the file path of selected file in list view to another form. please help me.
here the codes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd= new OpenFileDialog() { Filter="All files (*.*)|*.*|Media Files|*.mp4;*.mkv;*.mpeg4", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = true, })
        {
            if(ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<MediaFile> files = new List<MediaFile>();
                foreach(String f in ofd.FileNames)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f);                
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem((listView1.Items.Count + 1).ToString());                
                    item.SubItems.Add(fi.Name);
                    item.SubItems.Add(fi.FullName);
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(listView1.Items[0]);
        frm2.Show();


    }
```

form 2 code :

```
public Form2(ListViewItem item)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
        }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything we cant help you

Comment: i tried but no use of it

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: i posted the picture

Comment: we just want the relevant portions.  `Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `Form2(ListViewItem item)` functions in your question.

Comment: also, are you getting a `NullReferenceException` or `ArgumentOutOfBoundException` with `item.SubItems[2].Text`? if so, include that in your question.

Comment: @ShaluAwzme - Please don't post images of your code. Post the text itself. It's much easy for us to work with and when it's easy for us you get better answers.

Comment: Sorry....!! Iam first time here..!!next onwards I'll do correctly..!!

Comment: @Brett Caswell No there are no any exceptions...the path text is passing to the text box but it's not playing...it just automatically get closed with error code 0 while clicking play button

Comment: your question and title do not reflect your actual issue.

Comment: Try assigning to the `Url` **before** doing `play()`; since the control uses `Url`, and you seem to be trying to use a local file, try specifying the `"file:\\"` protocol in that assignment:  `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = string.format("file:\\{0}", textBox1.Text)`